# How can I see my external drive in the potplayer network section

Tags: homegroup

I currently have 4 PC hooked up, obviously I can't plug my main drive into all of them. I figure the simplest solution would be to share my media through a secondary router I hooked up, only my computers are connected to it. I tried creating a homegroup, but it always tries to open with windows media player, and that is unacceptable. It's not that I need to change all .mp4 files to open with potplayer for example, it's when I try to display files over the homegroup, the only program windows will allow me to use regardless of file association is windows media player. Is there a simple way to make the homegroup open with the right program, or is it absolutely necessary to rely on a third-party program? There are other options if this doesn't pan out, I could try relying on the USB port in my router for example, but if I do it this way I could see all drives in my PC.